# Meteor-React JSX: How to Tweet on behalf of the user

Tags: meteor, twitter, reactjs, meteor-accounts

I am trying to tweet on behalf of my app user. I have a Meteor app and after using Meteor.loginWithTwitter, I would like to tweet on behalf of my user (`Meteor.user().services.twitter.screenName`). I don't know how to accomplish this. This might be possible with **Twit** library but I can't get tokens of my user dynamically to modify Twit config.

Comment: Check out the Twitter APi.

Comment: you mean dev.twitter.com/rest/public ? If yes, can you give me a code sample of tweeting on behalf of a user from Meteor?

Comment: the doc is here:
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update

Comment: Resource URL
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json

Comment: use Meteor.http   http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http

Comment: or use one of the dozens of packages for twitter on Atmosphere... https://atmospherejs.com/?q=twitter

Comment: Thanks. I will give a try

Comment: I tried that but I am getting ""Bad Authentication data"". I guess I also have to pass a token. If that's true how can i get it out of loginWithTwitter? Meteor.user().services.twitter doesn't have a token for twitter.

Comment: You need: 1) to create a Twitter App, get a API key and token. 2) You need to have your users approve the permissions you ask for (and I don't know what permissions you need to tweet on behalf of someone, but you must set that up in the Twitter App page. Then with yoru API key you can login and make requests

Comment: I have an app under my twitter account. When user tries to log in, Twitter login page come up asking to authorize my app to be able to see friends list, post, ... After logging in, Meteor creates a user info under Meteor.user().services.twitter. However, I get stuck on retrieving token of the user. In order for me to get this far, I used Meteor accounts-twitter and service-configuration modules. Seems like I am missing very last step of getting user's tokens after Meteor.loginWithTwitter. Sorry if I am asking to many question but I am new to this :)

Comment: the accounts-twitter package gives you the tokens. But you really don't need the token, you need the user ID. You need to LOGIN to the Twitter API with YOUR App API key, and then you make a request for that user's id

Comment: What exactly do you mean by logging in to Twitter API with my customer key? How can i do that in the code(is it another HTTP request?). After user logs in, I send a request as you suggested               `HTTP.call("GET", "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/list.json?user_id="+id, function(data){
                    console.log("Success");
                });` but I am still getting _Bad Authentication data_

Comment: the docs is here: https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/authorizing-requests

Comment: Looks like currently Twitter requires tokens.  Based on the link that you sent me, it still needs **Authorization**. I have my app's oauth_consumer_key and oauth_token. How can I dynamically get the remaining data to complete **Authorization**? Is it another `HTTP.call("GET", "https://api.twitter.com...)` call?

Comment: Dude, it is all explained in the page I sent. Read the docs. You need to generate the signature from rrandom data and base64 encode it. that is the only thing you are missing.

Comment: @user2646559 you can generate `oauth_nonce` with random package... for `oauth_timestamp` try `new Date()`.... i also interest with this,, let me know if you success...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem with posting on behalf on my user is that I didn't update Twit config using my user's token which was in Meteor.user().services.twitter.
Trick was that if you call Meteor.user().services.twitter from a client-side it doesn't have tokens that you need but if you do it from a server-side, you get your tokens and life is good again. Thanks MrE for helping me to get here.